# Oracle in instantclient_12_2 ODBC driver could not be loaded

Tags: sql, database, oracle, odbc, instantclient

I Was trying to do the connection between Oracle and QT while I'm in creating a new data source there were a problem that I couldn't solve

[first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcydw.png)

[2nd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5NZg.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6xPu.png)

when I go and check the instant client I found sqoras32.dll I don't know why it says sqoras32.dll not found ..

I tried a lot of solutions like installing visual c++ 2010 , copying the sqoras.dll and pasting it in system32... but none of them worked 
can anyone help me please , Thanks!

PS:all my classmates did the same steps and it worked for them.

and that's what I have in

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in instantclient12_2
"APILevel"="1"
"CPTimeout"="60"
"ConnectFunctions"="YYY"
"Driver"="C:\instantclient12_2\SQORA32.dll"
"DriverODBCVer"="03.51"
"FileUsage"="0"
"Setup"="C:\instantclient12_2\SQORAS32.DLL"
"SQLLevel"="1"
```

---

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers
 "Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)"="installed"
 "Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)"="installed"
 "Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)"="installed"
 "Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)"="installed"
 "Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db)"="installed"
 "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)"="installed"
 "Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)"="installed"
 "Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)"="installed"
 "Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)"="installed"
 "Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)"="installed"
 "Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)"="installed"
 "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle"="installed"
 "Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )"="installed"
 "Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )"="installed"
 "Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)"="installed"
 "Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)"="installed"
 "Oracle in instantclient12_2"="installed"
 "SQL Server"="installed"
```

Comment: Obviously there is **something different** about what your classmates have done and what you are doing. Maybe it's something about your environment or configuration. Maybe you've missed a step or mistyped a parameter. There is very little we can do to debug your installation remotely. On the other hand there is a great deal you can do with the assistance of one of your classmates.

Comment: Is folder `c:\Instantclient_12_2` in your `%PATH%` environment variable?

Comment: Open your Registry editor. What do you have in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in instantclient_12_2`?

Comment: yes its my path

Comment: The show your registry entries (edit the question). In best case put in text rather than screen shots.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit check my post I added  2 pictures that shows  what I have in my HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in instantclient_12_2?

Comment: Do you think that we are visionary and can see the truncated text in you picture? Move the borders that we can read the relevant text!

Comment: Do you have both files sqora32.dll and sqora**s**32.dll?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I removed the screenshots and wrote it as a text , yes I have sqora32.dll and saqoras32.dll.

Comment: The folder in your Registry is `C:\instantclient12_2` instead of `C:\instantclient_12_2` - verify carefully.

Comment: yeah I saw it and I did modify all the C:\instantclient_12_2 to C:\instantclient12_2 in the TNS_ADMIN,the path ...

Comment: is there anything else that it looks like causing the problem .. what should I do ?

Comment: Somehow you mixed the folders. I would recommend to uninstall the ODBC driver and install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I could fix it by installing all visual studios from 2005 to 2017(x64 nd x86) now it works correctly 
thanks for all those who tried to help .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to use the information found in this post to fix it.

Out of helping others the following link is where to find the downloads.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Direct links to Redist:

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.arm64.exe

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe